# How to find out how many EF Core queries are executed during an request processing

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

We have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 and EF Core 5.0 project. We'd like to implement a query counter which will look at how many EF Core queries executed against a database during an API execution. The `DbContext` is injected to the controllers using ASP.NET DI with `AddScoped` method.

Anyone have any ideas of how to implement this? Maybe with a EF Core interceptor or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is using `IDbCommandInterceptor`
Create class which is derived from `DbCommandInterceptor`. It should be thread safe.

```cs
public class MyCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public IMyStatistics Statistics { get; }

    public MyCommandInterceptor(IMyStatistics statistics)
    {
        Statistics = statistics ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(statistics));
    }

    public override DbCommand CommandCreated(CommandEndEventData eventData, DbCommand result)
    {
        Statistics.IncrementCommandCount();
        return base.CommandCreated(eventData, result);
    }
}
```

Collect data using `IMyStatistics` interface. Realization also should be thread safe.

```cs
public interface IMyStatistics
{
    long CommandCount { get; }
    long IncrementCommandCount();
}

public class MyStatistics : IMyStatistics
{
    private long _commandCount;

    public long CommandCount => _commandCount;
    public long IncrementCommandCount()
    {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _commandCount);
    }
}
```

And configure your options:

```cs
_statistics = new MyStatistics();

optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new MyCommandInterceptor(_statistics));
```

Ensure that `_statistics` is singleton or created in right scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/event-counters?tabs=windows)

I think this tool will solve the problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Amirhossein. I think event counters might work, but need a bit more digging. Like how can we count the query executed divided by APIs? This is what I meant. Question updated to make it clearer.